# Generate all elements of a power set

Tags: java, algorithm, combinatorics, set, bitset

```
/*
 * Power set is just set of all subsets for given set.
 * It includes all subsets (with empty set).
 * It's well-known that there are 2N elements in this set, where N is count of elements in original set.

 * To build power set, following thing can be used:

 * Create a loop, which iterates all integers from 0 till 2^N-1
 * Proceed to binary representation for each integer
 * Each binary representation is a set of N bits (for lesser numbers, add leading zeros).
 * Each bit corresponds, if the certain set member is included in current subset. 
 */
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.BitSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class PowerSet<E> implements Iterator<Set<E>>, Iterable<Set<E>> {
    private final E[] ary;
    private final int subsets;
    private int i;

    public PowerSet(Set<E> set) {
        ary = (E[])set.toArray();
        subsets = (int)Math.pow(2, ary.length) - 1;
    }

    public Iterator<Set<E>> iterator() {
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public void remove() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Cannot remove()!");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return i <= subsets;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<E> next() {
        if (!hasNext()) {
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        }
        Set<E> subset = new TreeSet<E>();
        BitSet bitSet = BitSet.valueOf(new long[] { i });
        // get the index of truth values.
        for (int e = bitSet.nextSetBit(0); e != -1; e = bitSet.nextSetBit(e + 1)) {
            subset.add(ary[e]);
        }
        i++;
        return subset;
    }

    // Unit Test
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Set<Integer> numbers = new TreeSet<Integer>();
        for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
            numbers.add(i);
        }
        int count = 0;
        PowerSet<Integer> pSet = new PowerSet<Integer>(numbers);
        for (Set<Integer> subset : pSet) {
            //System.out.println(subset);
            count++;
        }
        assert count ==  (int)Math.pow(2, numbers.size()): "Total number of elements should be 2^N";
    }
}
```

The code is running fine. I am trying to learn `assert` for unit testing the code as well. The main issue is the elements seem to come out of order. Is there any way to maintain `lexicographical order`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Power of 2

Instead of using:

```
(int)Math.pow(2, numbers.size())
```

You can compute a power of two more efficiently like this:

```
1 << numbers.size()
```

You can use `1L` to compute it as a long if you think that the power may exceed 31.

## Manual bit manipulation

Instead of using a `BitSet` to find the 1 bits in your `int`, you can use integer arithmetic to check the bits yourself:

```
    for (int bit = 0; bit < 32; bit++) {
        if ((i & (1 << bit)) != 0) {
            subset.add(ary[bit]);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

regarding maintaining order - i think if you define subset as `SortedSet` (which is another interface that `TreeSet` implements) then you will get a subset where the elements are ordered according to their natural ordering (which is lexicographical), providing they are Strings of course.

regarding unit testing, the de-facto standard framework in Java is Junit, which uses `assert` and enhances it.

Comment: I have used `assert` in main method. Isn't this sufficient for programming practices?

Comment: you have only one test case? really? there are usually more. consider edge cases of null arg, empty set arg, etc. junit is a good framework for developing and maintaining a suite of test cases

Comment: Ah, ya I agree that was just start, I will surely add more tests in fact I need to learn testing properly too. Sure I will have a look into `JUnit` too.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> * It's well-known that there are 2N elements in this set
> ```

You mean 2^N.

> ```
> import java.util.List;
> import java.util.ArrayList;
> ```

These imports are unused.

> ```
> private final E[] ary;
> ```

Spell out the full name: `array`. Or better, use a name which describes the purpose of this field, like `allElements`.

> ```
> private final int subsets;
> ```

This should be `numSubsets`.

> ```
> private int i;
> ```

`i` is too short a name for a field. Consider using `currentSubsetIndex` or another descriptive name.

> ```
> ary = (E[])set.toArray();
> ```

This triggers an unchecked operation warning. You may want to use
 `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` before the constructor or use [this version](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#toArray%28T[]%29) of Set#toArray. I don't know what is the preferred way.

> ```
> numSubsets = (int)Math.pow(2, array.length) - 1;
> ```

Use bit shifting as @JS1 suggests to avoid floating point rounding issues.

> ```
> public Iterator<Set<E>> iterator() {
>     return this;
> }
> ```

Calling `iterator` on the same `PowerSet` returns the same object. Therefore looping twice over the same `PowerSet` using a for-each loop won't work as expected. [Iterables are not Iterators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836174/java-iterator-and-iterable#5836220).

---

I also recommend that you use @JS1's implementation of `next`, and learn how to use `JUnit` as @sharonbn suggested. (Maybe the test suite would make good reviewable code too.)

---

EDIT:

> The main issue is the elements seem to come out of order. Is there any way to maintain lexicographical order?

Sets are unordered. If you want a specific order for the subsets' elements, don't use `Set` (for input or output).